# Semantic UI Search selection dropdown is not working in safari

Tags: semantic-ui

I work with **semantic UI** and loading the dropdown options dynamically. I am loading the first dropdown on page load. while selecting the options in the first dropdown, the second dropdown will be loaded.

**For example** : If we select country the corresponding states will be loaded in second dropdown.

But this is not working in safari.Its working in chrome.Can anyone help me?

This is my code:

```
$("#selectdd1").change(function () {       
$.ajax({
    url: apiUrl,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: this.value,
    type: 'GET',        
    success: function (ResultSet) {                       
        $('.selectdd2').find('.menu').html("");            
        $('#selectdd2').empty();
        var $menu = $('.selectdd2').find('.menu');
        $('#selectdd2').append('<option value="">Select a Company</option>');
        for (var CMPIndex = 0; CMPIndex < ResultSet.length; CMPIndex++) {
            var tempValue = $.trim(ResultSet[CMPIndex].Value);
            $('#selectdd2').append('<option value="' + tempValue + '" keycode="' + ResultSet[CMPIndex].Key + '">' + tempValue + '</option>');
            $menu.append('<div class="item" data-value="' + tempValue + '">' + tempValue + '</div>');
        };
       $('#selectCompany').dropdown({
            placeholder: "Select",
        });          
    }
});
});
```

HTML Page

```
 <div class="form-group selectDD1">
     <select class="ui search selection dropdown dropdown-spinner 
      centwidth" id="dd1" name="dd1">
            <option value="">Select a Broker</option>
      </select>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group selectDD2">
     <select class="ui search selection dropdown dropdown-spinner 
      centwidth" id="selectdd2" name="select">
            <option value="">Select a Broker</option>
      </select>
 </div>
```

Comment: Did u got solution..??? Am Facing same issue now

Comment: Any idea for safari...??